# Disabling auto-revert-mode (Mac OS built via homebrew)

Tags: macos, emacs, homebrew

I have an unusual situation: After recently upgrading my emacs via homebrew to 25.2, I've noticed that all of my buffers have the `auto-revert-mode` minor mode set. Except, I don't reference this mode *anywhere* in my configuration. It just appeared. I have even tried to disable it with something like:

```
(when (fboundp 'global-auto-revert-mode)
  (global-auto-revert-mode -1))
```

That did not make a difference.

I have also exited emacs and hand-edited the `.emacs.desktop` file (in vim, shamefully) to remove every occurrence of `auto-revert-mode`. And yet, when I restart emacs it has returned, on every file-visiting buffer.

Comment: Recursively bisect your init file to find the code that is turning on auto-revert everywhere. (Then take care of that at the source - where it is being turned on.)

Answer (score 1):

In order to disable `auto-revert-mode` globally, try inserting the following line in your emacs initialization file.

```
(global-auto-revert-mode nil)
```

It's entirely possible that it's being set from another package or configuration file.  If that's the case, you can try adding the following lines to your initialization file.

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook
    (lambda () (global-auto-revert-mode nil))
```

If you find that `auto-revert-mode` is still being set, then it seems likely that you're setting it via another hook.  It's difficult to diagnose without a copy of your emacs configuration.  However, as a sort of brute force, the following lines of code should permanently disable `auto-revert-mode` (by the crudest means possible.)

```
(add-hook 'auto-revert-mode-hook
    (lambda () (global-auto-revert-mode nil))
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering this here for people who may find this question in the future:

The actual culprit was not `auto-revert-mode` after all, it was **magit**. Specifically, `magit-auto-revert-mode` that kicks in for any file-visiting buffers for whom the file is git-tracked.

It appeared to be a Mac issue only because I only saw it at home, on my MacBook, where all my code is GitHub-based. The exact same configuration at my Linux desktop (at work) didn't exhibit the problem because $DAY_JOB uses Perforce rather than git.

The developers of magit seem to think that this is an important feature, enough-so that there is no option to disable it (other than explicitly calling `(magit-auto-revert-mode nil)` somewhere). I'll consider mentioning this to them, but I suspect from the way they tout this in the documentation that they won't see any real need for a configuration setting.